Short story set in the future after some sort of disease or environmental disaster has destroyed all paper
I'm looking for a short story which I think must have been written before widespread access to personal computers.
It is set in the future after some sort of disease or environmental disaster has destroyed all paper. As a consequence the twentieth century is a poorly understood dark age for future historians.
I think I read it in 2009 but it long predates that. Any help in tracking it down would be greatly appreciated.

interesting idea since there was a time, not too long ago (less than 300 years) when paper was very hard to make and thus expensive and relatively rare. if you look at Newton's writings, you see very small handwriting and extensive use of abbreviations which no doubt had something to do with this; just the opposite of today when anyone with Internet access can take up pretty much infinite space with any sort of nonsense. i think quantity has gone way up and quality, way, way down.

It's not a short story, but this matches the backstory of Memoirs Found in a Bathtub (original title Pamiętnik znaleziony w wannie) by Stanisław Lem.
Quoting the plot summary on Wikipedia:

Memoirs Found in a Bathtub starts with the finding of a diary in the distant future. The introduction dwells on the difficulties of historical research on the fictional 'Neogene Era', "the period of the heyday of the pre-Chaotic culture, which preceded the Great Decomposition". "Great Decomposition" refers to the apocalyptic event of "papyrolysis", decomposition of all paper on the planet in the pre-information-technology era, causing all records and money to turn into dust––the end of the "epoch of papycracy".


One may admire the description of the "Third Pentagon", an organizational unit praying to the mysterious deity Kap-ee-tal, which has lost all touch with reality and pretends to manage even remote star systems while in reality just being a purposeless bureaucracy living out its dying fantasies in a vast underground bunker.
